# ad-hoc wifi on Android

Tags: android, wifi

Is it possible to connect two android phones (rooted) with wifi programatically and exchange data?

I know it is possible to do tethering using wifi-android-tether. But i need to establish the connection, and exchange the data, all through my android application. User intervention like switching on the android tether app manually is not allowed.

SO basically its like, if i run my app on two droid phones, they should do the following,

1. Detect that they have wifi.
2. DEtect that the other phone has its wifi on.
3. Establish a connection ( similar to a PAN in bluetooth ).
4. Exchange some data.

Comment: try http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Use [WiFi Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). The sample codes in the SDK package will do for testing Peer-Peer connectivity.